# Matrix problems over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, finite-fields, equivalence-relations

Assume $F_p$ is a finite field, $|F_p|=p$ and $M_n(F_p)$ is all the $n\times n$ matrices over $F_p$.

A relation is defined over $M_n(F_p)$:$$A,B\in M_n(F_p),A\sim B \Leftrightarrow \exists~~u,v\in \mathbb{Z^+}~~A^u=B^v.$$

It is easy to verify that this is an equivalence relation..

So for any $A\in M_n(F_p)$, we define
$$S_A=\left\{B\in M_n(F_p)|B\sim A\right\}.$$

So we have $$S_0=\left\{ B\in M_n(F_p)|B\sim 0 \right\} $$  and  $$S_I=\left\{ B\in M_n(F_p)|B\sim I \right\},$$ where $0$ is the $0$ matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix.

The question is how to calculate the cardinality of  $S_0$ and  $S_I$.

If we define
$$S=\left\{S_A|A\in M_n(F_p)\right\},$$

the question is how to calculate the cardinality of  $S$.

By reviewing the article, I have known that $S_0$ is the $\mathrm{Fine}-\mathrm{Herstein}$ theorem, so $|S_0|=q^{n^2-n}.$

I would like to ask about the remaining two questions.

I would like to get some articles or links to articles.

Thanks.

Comment: As I understand it $S_I$ is just the invertible matrices? So $|S_I| = |GL_n(F_p)| = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} p^n - p^k$

Comment: To count the number of equivalence classes you'd want to count the number of idempotent matrices over $F_p$. Someone gives a way to do this in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4021445/636419)

Comment: @ jacob If $A\in S_I$, I know $A$ is a invertible matrix. But if $B$ is a invertible matrix, can $B$ satisfy the existence of $u\in\mathbb{Z} ^+$ such that $B^u = I$?  I don't know if this holds up.

Comment: @easytoprovebydefinition $GL_{n}(F_{p})$ is a finite group, and so every element has finite order by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @ Alex Wertheim Oh，you are right. I ignore it. Thanks！

Comment: @jacob That formula looks good if $p$ is prime, which wasn't actually stated.

Comment: @aschepler The title says finite fields, so $p$ is prime or a prime power, and the formula works either way. It is an interesting question over arbitrary $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ though: I found [this](https://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/pommeren/Cryptology/Classic/9_Lin/NumbInv.pdf) which gives an answer

Comment: @jacob I see now that it does still work unaltered for prime powers. Interesting!

Answer (score 3):

For every endomorphism $\phi$ of a finite dimensional $K$-vector space there are uniquely determined complementary subspaces $V,W$ such that the restriction of $\phi$ to $V$ is nilpotent and the restriction of $\phi$ to $W$ is invertible*. In the current situation $A\sim B$ holds if and only if the subspaces $V,W$ and $V',W'$ so associated to the operations of multiplication by $A$ respectively by$~B$ satisfy $V=V'$ and $W=W'$. So the equivalence classes are parametrised by the ordered direct sum decompositions of $F_p^n$ into two complementary subspaces; the number of elements in the class for $(V,W)$ is the product of the number of nilpotent matrices over $F_p$ of size $\dim V$ (which can be derived from the formula given in the question) and the number of invertible  matrices over $F_p$ of size $d=\dim W$, which is well know to be $\prod_{i=0}^{d-1}(p^d-p^i)$. So you can work out the sizes of all the classes; the classes of $0$ and $I$ are the easiest ones.

*The space $V$ is the generalised eigenspace for $\lambda=0$, and if that space is the kernel of $\phi^k$ then $W$ is the image of $\phi^k$.